# AngularJS - Run jQuery on route change - Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have some jquery code that I need to run when the route is changed in a single-page angular app.

The app.run function clearly works, because I've added a js alert to run whenever the route changes, and that appears correctly, but the jquery I've also tried to run on the route change doesn't work.

JS:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
    console.log('$routeChangeSuccess: ', current);
    alert('route changed');
    $('ul.tabs').tabs({
        fullWidth: true
    });

    $('select').material_select();

    $('.select-wrapper span.caret').empty().removeClass('caret').addClass('fa').addClass('fa-angle-down');

    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true,
        selectYears: 15,
        today: 'Today',
        clear: 'Clear',
        close: 'Cancel',
        closeOnSelect: true,
    });

    $('.tabs-content').css('height','auto');
})
})
```

Comment: Avoid using `jQuery` in you controllers/run blocks while working with AngularJs. Try wrapping it with [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: What package are you using for routing ? Did you check if you are latching on to the correct event name.

Comment: I'm using ngRoute/routeProvider not ui-router